# Is there anything I'm supposed to have read before starting Kochikame?

Tags: kochikame

In the first volume of the manga series *Kochikame*, there was neither any introduction of the characters whatsoever, nor any explanation of the situation at all. In the second chapter, two new characters were introduced but it was as if they had been shown in the manga before. I'm really confused about this, so did I miss something in the manga?

Comment: Kochikame is a lightweight comedy manga - does it really need lengthy explanations or character introductions? You learn right off the bat that the main characters are these two policemen; there's your characters and your premise. Then they do some funny policeman things, and then the author adds some more characters so they can do different funny policeman things, and so on and so forth. (Also, I had a look at [volume 1](http://sokuyomi.jp/product/kotirakatu_001/CO/1/); there's no introductory material before the start of chapter 1.)

Comment: @senshin i get what you're saying and i'm not saying that it needs one, i'm just asking if i missed something because it feels like i missed something, especally the way they introduced the old man/god guy and his granddaughter, i've only seen it used when the reader has already met the character, so i got confused and that's all